# Getting the value of spark-submit parameters: num-executors, executor-cores and executor-memory

Tags: apache-spark

I was reading many questions about this topic on SO, and I've made a humble bash script to get these values fast.

The main sources to create the script were:

- http://site.clairvoyantsoft.com/understanding-resource-allocation-configurations-spark-application/
- https://spoddutur.github.io/spark-notes/distribution_of_executors_cores_and_memory_for_spark_application.html

The script contains the following:

```
# fixed values
CORES_PER_EXECUTOR=5    #  (for good HDFS throughput) --executor-cores
HADOOP_DAEMONS_CORE=1
HADOOP_DAEMONS_RAM=1


# Example values
# This information can be obtained using the `lscpu` command
total_nodes_in_cluster=10    # `CPU(s):` field of lscpu
total_cores_per_node=16     # `Core(s) per socket:` field of lscpu
total_ram_per_node=64      # using `free -h` command

available_cores_per_node=$((total_cores_per_node - HADOOP_DAEMONS_CORE))

available_cores_in_cluster=$((available_cores_per_node * total_nodes_in_cluster))

available_executors=$((available_cores_in_cluster / CORES_PER_EXECUTOR))

num_of_executors=$((available_executors - 1 )) # Leaving 1 executor for ApplicationManager

num_of_executors_per_node=$((available_executors / total_nodes_in_cluster))

mem_per_executor=$((total_ram_per_node / num_of_executors_per_node))

# Counting off heap overhead = 7% of `mem_per_executor`GB:
# TODO "Counting off heap overhead = 7% of 21GB = 3GB. ???
seven_percent=$((mem_per_executor / 7))
executor_memory=$((mem_per_executor - seven_percent))

echo -e "The command will contains:\n spark-submit --class <CLASS_NAME> --num-executors ${num_of_executors} --executor-cores ${CORES_PER_EXECUTOR} --executor-memory ${executor_memory}G ...."
```

I would like to know:

- Could anybody help me to understand the "Counting off heap overhead = 7% of `mem_per_executor`GB:" part? I mean, I did the math but I don't understand the idea behind.
- If the script is right and the values were taken for a real cluster, why did the Spark job was like "stuck" if I have been running the same job well but without any of those parameters?
- Any ideas to add to this script and get more parameters to send to `spark-submit`?

Thanks!